# How to get API Tooling to work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I have been having a real hard time getting API Tooling to work in Eclipse 3.4.2.  It keeps telling me:

The minor version should be incremented in version 3.4.0.qualifier, since new APIs have been added since version 3.4.0.40001

That being said, I have generated the plugins that are used for the baseline from the exact same code that it is being analyzed against.  The API Tools docs say that it compares the current code against the baseline to see if there are any differences.  I can't see how there could be differences if the built version is built from the current code.

The way that I tested it:

1. Create a new eclipse workspace
2. Create a new Plug-in Project with API Analysis turned on
3. Add a simple class to that plugin and export the package with that class in it
4. Build/Export that plugin to some location on your hard drive
5. Set the workspace baseline to that location and do a full build

You get an error for the project in your problems view.

Thanks,

-One very perplexed user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is something that got fixed in 3.5.  Too bad my company doesn't want us using 3.5 in case there are any incompatibility issues. (there were 3.3 to 3.4)

My recommendation to anyone who wants to do Eclipse API Analysis is to use 3.5.

Comment: We recently migrated our product from 3.2 base platform to 3.5 and even at such a great leap, the problems we encountered were minor and with some minor exceptions the basic transition wqas quite smooth...

Before we migrated, we had a analysis of the changes to the platform and we analyzed if it would make sense to migrate to 3.5 or 3.4 base platform.

As a result we found that API wise the most major changes fell between 3.2 and 3.4 bases and the actual amount of potentially incompatible changes between 3.4 -> 3.5 were just too small to outweigh the potential gains of a newer release...

Comment: Thanks. We are just making the transition ourselves.  I'll update with how the API analysis goes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I apologize for jumping on a thread late after its "active time" but I am currently running into this exact situation, but with Eclipse Helios 3.6.

From your answer, you noted that something was fixed in 3.5.  Are you aware of what this exact fix was AND if you have yet been able to verify that it is working under Eclipse Helios 3.6?

I would really like to have PDE API tooling working but I'm nearing my time allowed on this effort and need to move forward onto some pending tasks.

Thanks!

*EDIT: I would have posted this in a followup link but did not see any such links available.*

Comment: Hi Michael, we haven't added API analysis back in.  It got missed in our latest release and will hopefully be added in soon. I'm not sure what the exact fix was.  The problems we were seeing were that the API analysis would always say that there were changes, even with identical code.  I'll give it a try this week to see if it's working again.